# How to make LibreOffice Calc correctly interpret the desired number format for Time

Tags: macos, csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am appending to a CSV file programmatically with Python, which currently contain timings in the format: `0:1:10` (e.g. representing 0 hour, 1 minute, 10 seconds).

When I open the CSV file in LibreOffice Calc, with "Detect special numbers" activated, LibreOffice thinks that the format is `12:01:10 AM`.

Can I change Calc to per default use the time format interpretation `[HH]:MM:SS` which is what I want, instead of the current default `HH:MM:SS AM/PM`?

Or if not, should I format the time in my CSV file differently in order to make LibreOffice interpret the time correctly, and if so how (instead of `0:1:10`)?

My aim is for LibreOffice to correctly understand the time format when I open the CSV file, so that I can sum up the column quickly, without having to format the cells each time into the correct Time number format.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your difficulty. The amount will be calculated correctly regardless of the display format. The fact is that in fact `0:1:10` and `12:01:10 AM` for Calc mean the same number 0.000810185185185185, it is this number that will participate in the summation. One second in Calc is `1/(24 * 60 * 60) = 0.00001157407407407`

Comment: @JohnSUN The sum of 49 hours in my preferred time format should be 49:00:00. In the default time format, it is 01:00 AM.

Comment: Oh, just select the cell with the result, press Ctrl+1, select the required line in the Format field (like as your screenshot) and press Enter. If you want to get the period as a number of hours (for example, 49), then simply multiply the resulting sum by 24 and format it as a Number (not as Time). Check the time settings for your operating system, it is from there that LibreOffice takes the default formats. (This is in the locale settings, I can’t specify more precisely - I don’t know which operating system you are using: your form looks like MacOS, but it could be some of the Linuxes)

Comment: I am using MacOS. To be clear, my question is how to set the default format in Calc to automatically have it interpret the format as `[HH]:MM:SS`, or alternatively how to generate the text of the durations in such a way that LibreOffice selects this format rather than `HH:MM:SS AM/PM`. I don't want to do any manual number format selection e.g. via _CMD + 1_ or calculations in the document since it's time consuming.

Comment: Please see this [**topic**](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-dates-times-display-mac-mh27073/mac): *You can also select the Use a 24-hour clock option in the Clock pane of Dock & Menu Bar preferences.*